# Randomness in TensorFlow Dataset map function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Dataset of raw timeseries data that I have stored in TFRecords on disk:

```
dataset = TFRecordDataset(tfrecords)  # tfrecords is a list of filenames
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: do_something(x))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1024)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.batch(128)
```

What I would like my `do_something` function to do is, for each raw instance, take a random slice of the data so that I have a small window of data from the instance. But on the next epoch, I would like to ensure that I get a *different* random slice from each instance. My main question is, if introduce randomness into the `map` function (i.e. my `do_something` function), will it:

1. Just take random slices once from each raw instance and then continue to iterate over those same slices on each epoch.
2. Give me different random slices from each of the raw instances on each epoch.

I desire (2), so if that is not happening, is there an alternative way to achieve it?

For example, say I have 100 initial samples, each a timeseries of 50 data points. I want to generate 2000 samples of smaller slices, say 5-data-point slices. If I randomly select slices in my `map` function, will I just get the same 100 5-data-point slices on every `repeat`, or is there a way that I can get 100 *different* 5-data-point slices everytime I cycle through the 100 (50-data-point) initial samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get different random slices each epoch. Each epoch will call your `map` function again, so as long as your `map` function generates different slices each time it's called, you will get different slices.

Answer (score 0):

Without considering your `do_something` function, in `tf.data`, as long as you are having `shuffle` operation before `repeat`, you are guaranteed to have no repetitions of any sample till all the samples are iterated through once. So, by default you are bound to get the second characteristic which is *Give me different random slices from each of the raw instances on each epoch.*

Next, `map` function is meant for pre-processing stuff. It may be something like standardizing your data input, or reading images from filenames etc. You shouldn't be using `map` to shuffle your data. You should allow `shuffle` operation to perform random shuffling of your data.

**EDIT:**

Your question is still little unclear to me, but I believe you are having totally 100 samples each of 50 datapoints (let us call them *main samples*) and inside map function, you are going to randomly slice out 5 points from it (let us call them *subsamples*). Whatever I had written in my original answer, holds true for *main samples*. You will have no problems in repetitions of 100 *main samples* you generate in each `batch`. But at *subsamples* level, repeatibility depends upon how you have written your `do_something` function locally.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me, I will clarify in my description. Say I have 100 initial data samples, each one a timeseries of 50 data points. I want to generate 2000 timeseries samples, each one 5 data points in duration. My hope was to use the map function to create my 5-data-point slices, and then after I've gone through my 100 initial samples and got 100 slices, when I go back through again, I want to get 100 *different* slices.